# azure functions: Unable to add Diagnostics Settings from dashboard

Tags: logging, azure-functions, diagnostics

I am absolutely new to azure in general and azure functions in particular. I have successfully published some functions (for learning and testing purpose). Now I'm trying to add diagnostics settings to my service. For some unknown reason, the "save" button is disabled:

[image]

Not sure if it is related, but the `Log Analytics workspace` dropdown is empty. Could that be the reason.

Basically my ultimate goal is to enable monitoring so I can access error logs.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is very clear, you don't have a **Log Analytics workspace** when select **Send to Log Analytics options**.

Please first [Create a Log Analytics workspace in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace). Then set diagnostics settings again with the created **Log Analytics workspace**.

Another better way is using Application insights with azure function, which can provide more details. See [Monitor Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd) for details.